# Mapbox Static custom icon not found

Tags: mapbox

I uploaded a png icon to my webspace, which is accessible with this url:
https://hlsdb.de/icon/test.png

I now want to embed this icon in a static mapbox map. According the API docu, the following url should work:

https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v9/static/url-https%3A%2F%2Fhlsdb.de%2Ficon%2Ftest.png(8.400038,49.99284)/8.400038,49.99284,16,0,0/1200x514@2x?access_token=XXX

But i got the following response:

{"message":"Custom image not found"}

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what's wrong without knowing more about how you've configured the site you are trying to retrieve the marker icon from. How your .png is hosted certainly seems to be the issue.

When I replace your encoded uri with a different one, but keep the rest of the request intact, I get the expected results:

**query**

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v9/static/url-https%3A%2F%2Femojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com%2Fthumbs%2F320%2Fapple%2F198%2Fthinking-face_1f914.png(8.400038,49.99284)/8.400038,49.99284,16,0,0/1200x514@2x?access_token=XXX
```

**resulting image**
[image: marker overlay]

Do you have any `robots.txt` or other domain restrictions that might prevent the Mapbox service from retrieving the image? That's where I'd look first.

---

⚠️ disclaimer: I currently work at Mapbox ⚠️

Comment: Do you have any specific server-side restrictions in mind that could cause the problem? I have encountered the same behaviour (not working with resources from my own server but working with resources from other sources). I reviewed my server settings and made the desired images definitely accessible from the outside but the Mapbox API still shows the same error. I don't have a robots.txt.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the url you are trying to add as a marker overlay? Is it consistently failing or only sporadically? It could be any number of things from the url returning a 404 instead of the image, to it taking too long to respond with the image (i.e. latency), so it’s hard to say without taking a look at the request you are trying to embed.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reaction. I am trying to access the following resource: https://files.proptechtools.de/poi_icons/bewertungsobjekt_small.png. When encoded the link looks like this: https%3A%2F%2Ffiles.proptechtools.de%2Fpoi_icons%2Fbewertungsobjekt_small.png. The error occurs every time without exceptions. The apache log says the follwoing when starting the api request: [15/Oct/2020:20:35:37 +0200] "GET /poi_icons/bewertungsobjekt_small.png HTTP/1.1" 304 2812 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0".

Comment: Looks as if there is something wrong with your server's certifications. When I write a quick script to request it with Node.js, I see the following error:

```
{ Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1058:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:466:23)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:636:8) code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' }
```

Comment: I investigated according to your hint and was able to identify that there was a problem with a missing ssl intermediate certificate. After installing the additional certificate the api request works as it should. Thank you very much for helping out!